# LiveCD Ubuntu 12.04, can't open file "Kconfig"

Tags: 12.04, kernel, live-cd, make

I am going to try and make this as descriptive as possible so you know what I am looking to do and so it is clear.

**Error message:**

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Liquidware_BeagleBoard$ make menuconfig`

`scripts/kconfig/mconf arch/x86/Kconfig
drivers/staging/Kconfig:52: can't open file "drivers/staging/usbip/Kconfig"`

`make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 1`

`make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2`

**My situation:**

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 off a LiveCD on a new ThinkCentere with an Intel Core i5, 4GB RAM, and Windows 7 Enterprise. I cannot install Ubuntu onto the computer, but I can run it from the LiveCD.(Work Computer) I need to compile a kernel built by a company called Liquidware for a project I am on. Every time I try any `make` command that error is spat out. I have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04, but it would run out of memory(2GB RAM). So I know it is just with this computer and the LiveCD.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried this with `make menuconfig`, `make oldconfig`, and `make xconfig`. They all return the error above. I tried doing `sudo apt-get update` to make sure I wasn't missing any patch files. I even did `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`. Still no change. I located the folder and the file. Both have read and write permissions, including the containing folders too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the live CD or buy it? If you bought it then ship it back. If you created it as I did then retrace your steps and see if you made an error. I made my live CD with Daemon Tools Pro Advanced so if you have you can do as I did as I did if not buy it (34.99 euros, kinda pricey but worth it for the other possibilities) or look online for other options.

HOW TO: First download Ubuntu from the site--64-bit or 32-bit, your choice. Now you'll need to unzip the file and you'll **wubi** a few folders and a few files, take the Ubuntu .iso and mount it on any virtual drive and also insert DVD-R,  go into the Daemon Tools main console and and click "make disk image." Now let this run its process and once thats done u now have a disk image, all you have to do is take that DVD-R and pop it back in and press "Burn." Let that run its process and you now have shiny brand new Ubuntu live CD.

*If that doesn't work its your drive so your gonna have to get a new 1 or repair it, good luck.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you'll **wubi** a few folders and a few files"? Also, you seem to be saying to extract the contents of the ISO and then make a new disk image out of them. But the way you've described won't create a *bootable* disk image, will it?

Comment: Looks like make is possibly trying to build a kernel. Is your current directory the top of a kernel tree? If so, is there a drivers/staging/usbip/Kconfig? The Linux kernel menuconfig make file needs access to all of the individual config files distributed through the kernel tree, if I recall correctly. I suspect what you have downloaded rather than the live CD, although you may need to install some build dependencies, too, to make this work.

Comment: I created the LiveCD. Downloaded the .iso(didn't want to use wubi. Easier to use the .iso on a work computer) and used ImgBurn to burn it to a DVD(4.5GB). I am trying to compile the kernel. All the files are in the extracted .zip I got from Liquidware's GitHub page. The full path is lib/generic-pae-___/drivers/staging/usbip/Kconfig. I don't have access now and will be back at work on Monday. But I can try it here at my house to see if it is just the .iso or some other issue. John, your answer was helpful and I was doing just that, getting dependencies all afternoon.